# C# generic cannot convert from TypeA to TypeB

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am learning `C#` coming from `Java`, I know there is a number of such questions on this platform, I have checked them out but none of them explain my issue. I love the fact that `C#` and `Java` share a lot of similarities, it makes my transitioning much quicker and smoother, that said I am building an `API` that will return a `paginated result`, the pagination works great, the issue came in when I tried to introduce a `Single` response object that my `API` would return regardless of the endpoint, my response class looks like this

```
public class PaginatedResponse<T>
{

    public PaginatedList<T> PaginatedList;
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    public Boolean HasNextPage { get; set; }

    public Boolean HasPreviousPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalItemCount { get; set; }


}
```

I want it to return metadata about the pagination, this is suppose to work hand in hand with my pagination class which looks like this

```
 public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex > 1);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

Again like I said, the pagination works great, issue came in when I needed it to return `PaginatedResponse` and not `PaginatedList`

so I modified the `CreateAsync` method to look like this

```
public static async Task<PaginatedResponse<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {      
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

        return new PaginatedResponse<T>
        {
            PageSize = pageSize,
            TotalItemCount = count,
            HasNextPage = pageIndex < totalPages,
            HasPreviousPage = pageIndex > 1,
            PaginatedList = new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize)
        };

    }
```

My issue now is when I try to invoke the `CreateAsync` like

```
IQueryable<MyClass> source = SourceCreator.CreateSource();

return await PaginatedList<PaginatedResponse<MyClass>>.CreateAsync(source, page, pageSize);
```

It gives me the error

```
cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyClass>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<PaginatedResponse<MyClass>>'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `CreateAsync` returns a `PaginatedResponse<T>`. Your `T` is `MyClass`. `PaginatedResponse<MyClass>` is different from `PaginatedList<PaginatedResponse<MyClass>>`.

Comment: `CreateAsync` is a static method in the `PaginatedList` class, to access it I need to do something like `PaginatedList.CreateAsync` but because it has a return I need to know how to call it

Comment: In other words, when you call `PaginatedList<PaginatedResponse<MyClass>>.CreateAsync([...])` the `T` is now `PaginatedResponse<MyClass>` (and **not** `MyClass`!). But then you give it a `source` of `IQueryable<MyClass>` and the method rightfully refuses: hey, I wanted an `IQueryable<T>`. My `T` is `PaginatedResponse<MyClass>` so I expect an `IQueryable<PaginatedResponse<MyClass>>`. But you're giving me an `IQueryable<MyClass>`, as if you expected my `T` to be `MyClass` (which it isn't). If you want _that_ to work, ask my sibling `PaginatedList<MyClass>` to `CreateAsync`. maybe they can help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to call it like `PaginatedList<MyClass>.CreateAsync(source, page, pageSize)`